# Go Regex negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, go

I have a regex that works well for PCRE to detect a certain word without any special characters ahead of it. For example detecting T4 would work well with `(?!\S)T4(?!\S)`.

Match: `T4`

Not a match: `^T4` or `=T4`

However, I'm not certain if negative look behinds are supported by Go Regex. Is there something equivalent that can be used in Go Regex?

Comment: You do not need those lookarounds if you just check if a word is in between whitespace or start/end of string, just use `(?:\s|^)T4(?:\s|$)`

Comment: You are correct. That definitely works. Thanks!

Comment: "I'm not certain if negative look behinds are supported by Go Regex" -- They are not. This is covered extensively on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither negative lookbehinds nor lookarounds in general are supported by Golang regex.

You can check if there is a word in between whitespaces or start/end of string using

```golang
pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\s|^)T4(?:\s|$)`)
```

where

- `(?:\s|^)` - a non-capturing group matching either a whitespace or start of string
- `T4`  - a literal substring
- `(?:\s|$)` - a non-capturing group matching either a whitespace or end of string.